# Add static extension to generic type

Tags: kotlin, extension-methods, static-methods

I'd like to be able to do this

```
fun <A> doSomething(block: A.Companion.() -> Unit): Unit {
    // bla bla bla
    A.block()
}
```

Is it possible? If not? Is it in the roadmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your example is impossible and not in roadmap.

Not all classes have companion objects and there are no ability to check if the specific class has.

Comment: How about https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/companion-object-instance.html ?

Comment: @leonardkraemer I meant without using reflection :)

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking about a statically compiled time verified thing.

Comment: @caeus there are no way, as I told in answer :) If answer satisfies you, mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: I found this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11968. It looks like it's not in the roadmap and it looks that even if done, it won't apply for generic types.